# Когда вызывается __destruct

Tags: ооп, php

мне интересно стало когда вызывается _destruct :после удаления объекта или до?
Хочется узнать можно ли получать значения свойств объекта который мы собирается удалить внутри деструктора и свойств других объектов?
Маленький код который не работает:

```
class Boo{
    public $ty=10;
    function __destruct(){
        global $obj2;
        echo $this->ty.$obj2->grr;
    }
}

class Secon{
    public $grr=9;
}

$obj2=new Secon;
$obj=new Boo;

unset($obj);
```

Comment: Разве $obj2 глобальная переменная, что вы работаете с ней в функции?

Деструктор выполняется перед удалением, можно работать с переменными удаляемого объекта класса.

Возможно ошибаюсь, но у меня не работает код когда я объявляю переменную и сразу присваиваю ей значение в описании класса.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку с глобальной видимостью.

Comment: Знающие люди говорят еще, что надо физически уничтожать все переменные класса

If you use __destruct in your script manually it's not automatically unset the $vars inside the the script. 
 For that you can use following script to clean up the class. 

    <?php 
    public function __destruct() { 
             foreach ($this as $key => $value) { 
                 unset($this->$key); 
             } 
         } 
    ?>

Comment: Ведь у Вас версия php > 5? (на всякий случай)

Comment: ДА.Уже работает когда добавил флаг global+мистика денвера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня ваш код работает.

[__destruct()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) вызывается когда на объект не осталось ссылок, или во время нормального завершения работы скрипта. Да, ему доступны все методы и свойства класса.

Comment: "или во время нормального завершения работы скрипта. "-тоесть в влюбом случае он будет выполнен когда скрип закончит работу?

Comment: Если по Fatal'у вылетит, или класс не был инстанциирован, то не выполнится.

Comment: все спасибо...